# Running a PHP program in Ubuntu - fopen("filename", "w"): Failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, csv, ubuntu, fopen

I am using Ubuntu as my OS, and I have XAMPP in it. In the `htdocs` folder, I have created a project folder in which I have `index.php` file. Now inside the index.php, a part of the code does this:

```
fopen("colors_new.csv", "w");
```

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php),

> 'w'   Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of
>   the file and truncate the file to zero length. **If the file does not
>   exist, attempt to create it.**

But instead of the file being created, I am getting

```
Warning: fopen(colors_new.csv): failed to open stream: Permission denied...
```

**And when I look into the project folder, the `colors_new.csv` file is NOT created.**

**When I run this program in another computer running Windows OS, it runs successfully. The file is successfully created.**

How do I fix this problem in Ubuntu?

**WHAT I TRIED:**

I tried to run **`sudo chmod 777 colors_new.csv`** but I get **`chmod: can not access colors_new.csv. No such file or directory.`**. I tried this with just the file name (as shown) while the terminal WAS in the project directory; as well as by giving the full absolute path of the file. Got the same error both times.

---

**NOTE:** I have seen other questions, and as indicated above, I tried to give permissions to the file. The other questions did not solve the problem, the accepted answer below did solve it.

Comment: Before running the chmod command you have to at location of file. Otherwise it will throw the error: chmod: can not access colors_new.csv. No such file or directory

Comment: The issue is not with the file since it isn't created but with the folder / directory, you most likely don't have permission to create files in the directory / folder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that you don't have the rights to write a file in the directory where your index.php is. A couple of things you can do to make it work

- give filewriting permissions to the directory.
  Go with 755 on that and 644 on files, if settings are correct this is sufficient. Never go full [777](https://www.maketecheasier.com/file-permissions-what-does-chmod-777-means/), which is security risk.
- create a subdirectory inside your directory and give that sufficient rights (755) to do what you want.
  F.i. Fopen('./files/colors_new.csv)

Answer (score 2):

Provide the write permission on the folder in which you want to write the file. Your problem will be solved.

Comment: and how to I do that?

Comment: @Jesss Same way you did for the file, most typically your folder needs to have `755` or `775` depending on how your system is setup. But there are plenty of tutorials for that out there.

Comment: chmod options permissions filename